# Way to convert NotesDocument to NotesXspDocument

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, xpages-ssjs

I would like to know whether there is a way to convert Notesdocument to notesxspdocument.
or is there a way to know that notesdocument is in edit mode from serverside javascript agent?
thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [wrapDocument XSnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=wrap-notesdocument-into-notesxspdocument) to convert a NotesDocument into a NotesXspDocument.